# Capturing the screen quickly

Tags: java, multithreading, image, awtrobot

So I'm working on a screen recording program and what I do is take screen shots while the program is running and then convert it to a .mov file.

TO take a screen shot what I'm doing is

```
do {    
    try {

        r = new Robot();
        img = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle (0, 0, width, height));
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(JavCapture.tmpLocation + "\\tmp\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
        r = null;

        } catch (IOException | AWTException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    } while (!stop);
```

This is all in a thread that is is running as long as stop is not true, once it is the thread stops.

If I run this for 5 seconds I'll only get 9 images and the movie will be less than a second long.

**How can I optimize my code so that it takes pictures faster?**

Should I run the thread multiple times? Because when I try to do that

```
(new Thread(new Record())).start();
```

And I'll do it 3 times, yes more pics will be taken, but it'll take a lot longer (obviously but is there a way to speed it up) but it seems that only the pictures for one thread will be added. Here is my full thread code.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Record implements Runnable {

    Robot r;
    static int width = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
    static int height = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
    BufferedImage img;
    public static boolean stop = false;

    public void run() {

        do {    
            try {
                r = new Robot();
                img = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle (0, 0, width, height));
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(JavCapture.tmpLocation + "\\tmp\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
                r = null;
            } catch (IOException | AWTException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        } while (!stop);

        if (stop) {
            try {
                Utils.makeVideo("Video.mov");
                File f = new File (JavCapture.tmpLocation + "/tmp");
                Utils.deleteDirectory(f);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return;

    }

}
```

Is there a more efficient way that will take up less memory (I'm assuming the more thread the more memory will be used) and if not how can I edit the code so that all the images are used.

**NOTE: I'm using the JPEGImagesToMovie.java class to make the .mov file.

Comment: Put a small pause into your capture thread, something like `Thread.sleep(16)` for example.  Reduce the area you are capturing...

Comment: Wont placing a sleep slow it down? And I've made a small edit at the bottom, just want to make sure you noticed that.

Comment: You would think so wouldn't you.  It's going to give time for the other threads to breath.  16 milliseconds is roughly 60fps...do you seriously need more than that anyway.  Not saying it will work, but it can't hurt.  You could also offload the saving of the images to other thread as the IO throughput is going to be very high

Comment: So I've done some playing around, with a screen resolution of 2560x1600 using your code, I get roughly 9 frames over 5 seconds :P.  If I create a second thread, whose sole responsibility is to manage a list of `BufferedImages` and write them out, I get roughly 38 frames (or roughly 7 fps)...the problem is two fold.  Robot is woefully inefficient at capturing the screen and the I/O of writing the files out is very high...